# Python Syntax Highlighting in Xcode

Tags: python, xcode, xcode8, syntax-highlighting

Is there any way to achieve better syntax highlighting in Xcode for Python? Xcode only identifies and colorizes keywords, strings, numbers and comments. It doesn't seem to be able to identify the `self` variable name that represents instance objects. I've experimented with other color themes but it doesn't change the fact that Xcode cannot identify names for instance objects in Python. Is there any way to achieve better syntax highlighting?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Xcode 12; after you have setup Python properly in Xcode. Refer to [this YouTube video](https://youtu.be/h8_68OONY-w) if you are not sure of your setup.

Click on the 'Editor' tab on the menu bar, click on 'syntax colouring' and choose 'python' from the list and you will be fine.